# Shell pipe system in C

Tags: c, shell, pipe

I'm trying to make a pipe system for my shell, but it's not working as intended.

```
void pipes (char *listaCommand[], int end, char **argv)  
{  
    int cont = end;  
    for (cont;listaCommand[cont]; cont++)  
    {  
        if (listaCommand[cont] != NULL)  
        {
            if (!strcmp(listaCommand[cont],"|")){
                int pid2, status;
                int pipefd[2], ret;

                listaCommand[cont] = NULL;

                ret = pipe (pipefd);
                if (ret < 0) fatal();

                /* Now fork. */

                pid2 = fork ();
                if (pid2 <0) fatal ();

                if (pid2 > 0)
                {
                    printf ("P: waiting for child\n");
                    wait (&status);     
                    close(STDIN_FILENO);
                    dup(pipefd[0]);
                    close(pipefd[0]);
                    close(pipefd[1]);
                    /*execvp (auxCommand[0], auxCommand);*/
                    pipes(listaCommand, cont+1, argv);
                    /*break;*/
                }
                else
                {
                    close (STDOUT_FILENO);
                    dup (pipefd[1]);
                    close (pipefd[1]);  
                    close (pipefd[0]);

                }

            }
        }
    }
    if (end >= 3)
    {
        printf("%s \n", listaCommand[end-1]);
    }
    execvp (listaCommand[end], listaCommand);
    printf ("%s: command not found.\n", listaCommand[end]); /* Exec failed. */
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

If I use commands like ls | sort, it works, but if ls has any argument, it doesnt work, because for some reason, listaCommand[cont] where its == "|" is not NULL, so I just get
ls: option -- 'a' invalid.

```
listaCommand have  
[0] = "ls"  
[1] = "-al"  
[2] = "|"  
[3] = "sort"
```

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Why listaCommand[cont] where its equal "|" is not NULL for the process that execute the "ls" command, even though I'm attributing NULL for it before creating the new process?   Both process should have the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass the `end` argument, instead increment the pointer to your command array. You are passing the initial array to the execvp call so it tries to execute `ls` multiple times. Further, you need a break statement after setting the `listaCommand[cont]` to `NULL` because after the iteration `cont` is incremented. Also I think you need to protect the `execvp` call so that the parent does not call it after the processing is done.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#define fatal() exit(1)
void pipes (char *listaCommand[], char **argv)  
{  
    printf("pipes %s\n", listaCommand[0]);
    int cont = 0;
    for (;listaCommand[cont]; cont++)  {  
        if (listaCommand[cont][0] == '|'){
            int pid2, status;
            int pipefd[2], ret;

            listaCommand[cont] = NULL;

            ret = pipe (pipefd);
            if (ret < 0) fatal();

            /* Now fork. */

            pid2 = fork ();
            if (pid2 <0) fatal ();

            if (pid2 > 0)
            {
                printf ("P: waiting for child\n");
                wait (&status);     
                close(STDIN_FILENO);
                dup(pipefd[0]);
                close(pipefd[0]);
                close(pipefd[1]);
                /*execvp (auxCommand[0], auxCommand);*/
                pipes(listaCommand + cont + 1, argv);
                /*break;*/
            }
            else
            {
                close (STDOUT_FILENO);
                dup (pipefd[1]);
                close (pipefd[1]);  
                close (pipefd[0]);
                break;
            }

        }
    }
    if (listaCommand[0]) {
      execvp (listaCommand[0], listaCommand);
      printf ("%s: command not found.\n", listaCommand[0]); /* Exec failed. */
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

int main() {
    char *args[] = { "ls", "-al", "|", "sort", "|" , "tr", "[a-z]", "[A-Z]", 0 };
    pipes(args, 0);
    return 0;
}
```