# how to do pipelining in a shell

Tags: c, shell, pipe

I'm making a shell and I am stuck.

I have a function `perform(char* string, int infd, int outfd);`
This successfully takes a string and execs it, performing it perfectly.

examples: `"echo $$"` >> `"54321"`

`"echo $(dirname $(pwd))"` >> `"/home/solmjs/test"`

.

Now I have to make pipelining work, so that I can parse lines like this:

"finger | tail -n +2 | cut -c1-8 | uniq | sort"

I am very confused. How do I start?
I have a function that takes a string and expands it, by looking at the characters. I can search for '|' characters and if I do that, save the strings of the lines that come before and after:

finger | tail -n +2   >>  "finger" , "tail -n + 2"

then I call my `perform` function somehow connecting these two?
I know that in pipes the outfd connects to the infd of the next one but I don't understand how to do that between these two strings.
Thanks

Comment: Hint: `man 2 pipe` and `man 2 fork`

Comment: Would something like this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16929209/shell-pipe-system-in-c https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47478392/redirection-at-the-end-of-the-pipe-c-shell

Comment: that helped a lot, thank you. @JerryJeremiah